# $SO(N)$ symmetric theory of $N$ real scalar fields, why do charges have correct commutation relations of generators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, lie-algebra, noethers-theorem

Consider an $SO(N)$ symmetric theory of $N$ real scalar fields,$$\mathcal{L} = {1\over2} \partial_\mu \Phi^a \partial^\mu \Phi^a - {1\over2} m^2 \Phi^a \Phi^a - {1\over4} \lambda(\Phi^a \Phi^a)^2.$$For the quantum theory, consider the $SO(N)$ charges $\hat{Q}_{ab} = \int d^3 \textbf{x}\,\hat{J}_{ab}^0$. Why do the charges $\hat{Q}_{ab}$ have correct commutation relations of the generators of the $SO(N)$ symmetry?

Comment: Please give a definition of $\hat{J}^0_{ab}$. For instance, if one defines them in the "right" way, that is as the conserved currents under the obvious $\mathrm{SO}(N)$ symmetry, the question becomes rather trivial because the conserved charges of a symmetry generically are the generators of that symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let us consider the corresponding Hamiltonian theory, so that we have a notion of a commutator that we can use to form a Lie algebra bracket. Moreover, let us consider the classical theory for simplicity. Then the Poisson bracket 
   $$\tag{1} \{\Phi^a({\bf x}),\Pi_b({\bf y})\}_{PB}~=~\delta^a_b~\delta^3({\bf x}-{\bf y}),  \qquad \text{etc},$$
   plays the role of commutator.
2. The Hamiltonian Lagrangian density ${\cal L}_H$ for OP's theory is of the form
   $$\tag{2} {\cal L}_H~=~ \Pi_a \dot{\Phi}^a -{\cal H}, \qquad 
   {\cal H} ~=~ \frac{1}{2} \Pi^2 +{\cal V}(\Phi^2, (\nabla\Phi)^2) ,$$
   where we have introduced the notation
   $$\tag{3} \Phi^2 :=\Phi^a g_{ab} \Phi^b, \qquad  \Pi^2 :=\Pi^a g_{ab} \Pi^b,  \qquad \text{etc}. $$
3. Here the $o(N)$-indices $a,b,\ldots,$ are raised and lowered with a constant metric $g_{ab}$. The $O(N)$ symmetry 
   $$\tag{4} \delta \Phi^a ~=~ \varepsilon \{\Phi^a, Q[\omega]\}_{PB}~=~\varepsilon\omega^{a}{}_{b}\Phi^b, \quad \delta \Pi^a ~=~ \varepsilon \{\Pi^a, Q[\omega]\}_{PB}~=~\varepsilon\omega^{a}{}_{b}\Pi^b, \qquad  $$
   has generators
   $$\tag{5}  Q[\omega]~:= \frac{1}{2}\omega_{ab} Q^{ab} ~=~\Pi^a\omega_{ab}\Phi^b, \qquad  Q^{ab}~:=~\int\! d^3x\left( \Pi^a\Phi^b-\Phi^a\Pi^b\right), $$
   where
   $$\tag{6} \omega_{ab}~=~-\omega_{ba} $$ 
   are anti-symmetric matrices.
4. It is not hard to check that the generators (5) equipped with the Poisson bracket (1) form an $o(N)$ Lie-algebra. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28535/2451) related Phys.SE post.
5. The [Noether charges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem) are the generator of the symmetry, as is always the case for Hamiltonian theories, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69271/2451) Phys.SE post.
   This can also be explicitly confirmed in the above case.
6. We conclude that the Noether charges (5) form an $o(N)$ Lie algebra.
7. Finally, it seems that OP is also asking a more general question of whether any symmetry of any action lifts to a symmetry of the corresponding Noether charges? This is a good question and discussed in e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104422/2451) Phys.SE post. The answer is: *Not always! There can be either classical or quantum obstructions/anomalies, such as e.g. central charges and 2-cocycles.*